# Why MySql can not use PARTITION pruning with INSERT statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, partitioning

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-pruning.html) is a sentence:

> MySQL can apply partition pruning to SELECT, DELETE, and UPDATE statements. INSERT statements currently cannot be pruned.

So when a new row is inserted MySql can **not** determine what partition it belongs? Sound **very** strange. Is it a mistake? or what do they mean by this pharse?

Comment: Pruning insert statements may not strictly be needed.  Although the all the partitions might be locked, they do not have to be read.  The one exception I can readily think of is  validating records through `unique` constraints, but that should be quite fast across all partitions rather than just one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is mostly correct...  The exception does not exist -- `UNIQUE` and `FOREIGN KEY` are not handled because the code does not want to (and does not attempt to) check all the partitions.

Answer (score 2):

As I read it, the partition-pruning optimization currently relies on parsing of the `WHERE` clause to determine which partitions to access. The `INSERT` statement has no `WHERE` clause, and the optimizer **currently** has no **other** mechanism by which to prune.

It looks as though partition pruning is, at present, something of a work-in-progress.